# neo4j (v1.9.2) - webadmin can't connect to database with explicit url vs "localhost"

Tags: neo4j

Today I installed v1.9.2 on win7 64-bit server at fixed ip address 192.168.1.99

When I attempt to open the neo4j web admin, using explicit url  **192.168.1.99:7474/webadmin/**, I get a timeout error. However, when I replace the url with **localhost:7474/webadmin/**, then I connect without a problem. This is also problematic for my internal webapp as no else can access it without the server url.

Both **localhost** and **192.168.1.99** worked flawlessly with v1.9.RC2

Can anyone help me resolve this so that I can use the explicit url?

Can anyone recreate this to make sure I am not losing my mind?

Update: I also uncommented the line "org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0" in the neo4j-server.properties file. When commented, the database only listens on localhost (only accept local connections). This had no effect.

Update2: worked on some javascript - found a bug, fixed it, and now the explicit url is working. Not sure if this is a coincidence. Regardless, hope uncommenting "org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0" in the neo4j-server.properties file helps someone.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: What browser are you using? There seems to be a bug in the latest chrome around resolving localhost.

Comment: Was using Chrome and Firefox - appears to be working in both. I am thinking that I didn;t restart database or refresh browsers after uncommenting "org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0" Thanks for the heads up on resolving localhost in Chrome.